# configer hot letters in Eclipse plugin menu (& does not work)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, nodeclipse

As [Eclipse plugin developer](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/), how to specify what letter in menu item would be hot.

For example, when user open File -> New (e.g. with <kbd>Alt+Shift+N</kbd>), 
then
make `n` to select _N_ode.js project
make `p` to select _P_hantomJS project
etc

I think I just need to add special simbol before the letter

into [`name="Node.js Express Project"`](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/plugin.xml#L16)

but `&` does not work.

[image]
<sub>(source: [nodeclipse.org](http://www.nodeclipse.org/img/enide-studio/Enide-Studio-2014-File-New.png))</sub>

Comment: Look at the `org.eclipse.ui.bindings` extension point

Comment: [That](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_bindings.html) would have global impact. BTW even Java perspective does not have quick letters underlined. Only in main menu.

Comment: I found example of & usage in `plugin.properties` https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.ui.ide/plugin.properties but now cannot make my plugin use the `plugin.properties`

Comment: The plugin.properties is just a way of moving NLS text out of the plugin.xml. It is the plugin.xml that defines how these strings are used - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `&` as `&amp;`

```
        name="&amp;Node.js Project"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mnemonic` attribute of the `command` and `menu` elements in the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.ide.MarkersView">
      <command
            commandId="org.eclipse.ui.navigate.goToResource"
            mnemonic="X"
            style="push">
      </command>
  </menuContribution>

  <menuContribution
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.ide.MarkersView">

     <menu
           commandId="org.eclipse.ui.navigate.showInQuickMenu"
           id="org.eclipse.ui.ide.markers.showInMenu"
           label="Show In"
           mnemonic="Y">
```

Comment: Well, maybe that would work in some places, but for File -> New (<kbd>Alt+Shift+N</kbd>) the menu is automatically generated, based on defined wizards for the current perspective `factory.addNewWizardShortcut("org.nodeclipse.ui.wizards.NodeProjectWizard");` And of course there is no `mnemonic` attribute in `<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">`